# Under what conditions can I redistribute files from my local TeXLive installation

Tags: luatex, texlive

I created a [Github repository called *luatexminimal*](https://github.com/deepakjois/luatexminimal), to provide a minimal, barebones LuaTeX setup to compile PDF documents. I had to copy a few files from my local TeXLive installation to do that:

1. `plain.tex` and `hyphen.tex`
2. `.tfm` files for Computer Modern
3. `.pfb` file for Computer Modern Roman

What license should I release the code under?

Comment: That is a question for legal advice, which we don't give. The question is off-topic.

Comment: Check what the other files are licensed under and start your decison process with that knowledge.

Comment: All of those seem to be part of Knuth's core TeX system, in which case they carry Knuth's license ('do what you like but you must rename the files if you alter them at all, unless you are DEK'). More generally, you decide on the license for code _you write_, you have to _respect_ the license for code that others write.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you. Is there a copy of this license on the internet? Or is it literally just what you put in quotes?

Comment: @vyom See http://ctan.org/pkg/plain and the source files themselves. Knuth's code pre-dates the idea of 'licenses' (from the days when academics expected software to be distributed with acknowledgement), so it's more of a 'statement'.

Comment: @JosephWright You are right. I guess my real question would have been:  can I redistribute these files without violating the license? If yes, what are the restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision on what you can do with *any* file should be based first on reading what conditions it has attached. Whilst legal advice is *off topic*, the general idea that *all* works are copyrighted holds internationally. As such, it is up to the copyright holder to specify what you can do with the files.

For example, in the case of Knuth's `plain.tex` one can find at the start

> ```
> % This is the plain TeX format that's described in The TeXbook.
> % N.B.: A version number is defined at the very end of this file;
> %       please change that number whenever the file is modified!
> % And don't modify the file unless you change its name:
> %       Everybody's "plain.tex" file should be the same, worldwide.
>
> % Unlimited copying and redistribution of this file are permitted as long
> % as this file is not modified. Modifications are permitted, but only if
> % the resulting file is not named plain.tex.
> ```

which seems clear enough. (Note that one can argue whether Knuth's statement constitutes a license or not, but sticking to what this statement says is generally accepted as defensible.)

Comment: Note I've answered here as 'What distribution conditions apply to Knuth's files?' or similar is answerable I hope.

Comment: Can we retitle the question that way?

Comment: I have edited the title lightly, but I have left the body of the question unchanged so that the discussion in the comments is still relevant.

Comment: @JosephWright, it explicitly allows anybody some actions that the relevant law places in the hands of the copyright owner. It is a license.